# How to quit iPhone webapp programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, web-applications

I want to make a couple buttons on my iPhone to control my stereo. I thought I might be able to do this by putting a couple webpages on my homescreen that issue stop, play, next, etc requests to my media server that quit shortly after being opened. Is there a way to tell safari to quit other than crashing it? If not, what's the best way to crash safari? I realize this isn't very elegant, but I really want to have buttons on the homescreen, not in an app, and this was the best solution I could come up with.

I realize I could make the buttons native apps, but I don't want my iPhone running *any* third party software, even from myself (I have very little iOS programming experience, and even though I'm pretty sure there's a lot of sandboxing/this is trivial, I'm worried I'll mess up my phone). If you think I shouldn't worry about that and think it would be better to make these buttons native applications, or have any other suggestions, please let me know.

Comment: After rereading this, I think "deliberately crashing Safari" is probably more dangerous than writing a custom app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only is there no need for your web clips to be closed - just issue the command once - crashing Safari is a bad idea at best.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're right. I ended up making a webpage remote with all the buttons on one page.